# Save user group event in Control panel

Tags: users, permissions

I have a plugin that saves users into a registration group like:

```
 if (craft()->request->isSiteRequest()) {
  //etc 
  $groupId = '1';
  craft()->userGroups->assignUserToGroups($user->id, $groupId);
}
```

However if i listen for the user save event for the control panel:

```
if (craft()->request->isCpRequest()) {
  //etc 
  $groupId = '1';
  craft()->userGroups->assignUserToGroups($user->id, $groupId);
}
```

This doesnt work. I also tried passing an array as groupId(s) but the group permission never gets ticked.

Is there another way of assigning a new user saved in the back end to a specific permission group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens here (maybe intended, maybe a bug):

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/tree/master-v2/src/controllers/UsersController.php#L1757

For news users `$groupIds` is an empty string, which means the expression `($groupIds !== null)` becomes true. At line 1780 `$groupIds` get passed to userGroups->assignUserToGroups() ... inside this method the `$groupIds` variable is casted to an array.

Eventually this overwrites the groups you've set by your onSaveUser event.

---

Here is a (dirty) hack that works

```
craft()->users->onSaveUser = function ($event) {

   craft()->userGroups->assignUserToGroups($user->id, $groupId);
   craft()->params['noGroupReset'] = true;           

};



craft()->userGroups->onBeforeAssignUserToGroups = function ($event) {

   $noGroupReset = (isset(craft()->params['noGroupReset']) && craft()->params['noGroupReset'] === true);


   if (count($event->params['groupIds']) == 0 && $noGroupReset) {
      $event->performAction = false; 
   } 

};
```

Comment: Thanks Oliver - that kinda makes  sense if not comfort :). 
It seems that $groupId can be set via onSaveuser from the front end, and I guess not overwriting the admins choices is a sound reason, but for new users maybe a check could be made. I cant really see a neat solution. Seems that general plugin development around saving users has quite a few gotchas. Thx

Comment: @joomkit I've added a workaround